# How to get file from storage by public URL?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have application Laravel.

There is a storage by the path: `\storage\app\reports\`

I attempted to get file through GET url like:

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/app/reports/report_27-05-19_05.xlsx
```

But it does not work for me.

Also I tried to return file in backend side:

```
$file = File::get(storage_path($path.$filename));
$type = File::mimeType($path.$filename);

$response = Response::make($file, 200);
$response->header("Content-Type", $type);

return $response;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

The following example is for csv file stored in shared hosting

`$filename` is the name of the saved file which will be passed with `get` request

```
public function download($filename)
{
    $name = $filename;
    $file = $file = '/home/USERNAME/storage/report/'.$name;

    $header = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment',
        'Content-lenght' => filesize($file),
        'filename' => $name,
    );

    // auth code
    return Response::download($file, $name, $header);
}
```

Comment: Using absolute paths to the directory is bad practice + `Content-Type` forces the file to be served as `application/csv`. Also there is no need to send these additional headers. [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads)

Comment: Yeah, I know its a bad practice. I was not able to download my file without using it on shared hosting. Also, I wanted to download only csv when the user is logged in. That's why I posted my old code here. It was coded on Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Open your filesystem.php on config folder.

```
'reports' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/reports'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/app/reports',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

add this to disk array.

After the symlink probably works. Never tried, but could work. Give it a try.

Comment: And how to use it?

Comment: How to store and get?

Comment: Like this? ` Storage::disk('reports')->put($path.$filename, $content);` ?

Comment: for example on blade files you can call like => reports($file->filename) 
And yes, Storage::disk('reports') can assign to related folder.

Comment: How to get file by path? `\storage\app\reports\file.xml`?

Comment: yes, 
'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/app/reports'
You can change here what you want.

Comment: When I pass this url to browser it tried to apply route

Answer (score 0):

Your files are in the wrong folder if you want them publicly accessible (without controller).

#### Symlink

If you want your files to be public accessible.

1. Move your files to `storage/app/public`, run `php artisan storage:link`. This will symlink `storage/app/public` to `public/storage`. Your files will be publicly accessible now at `http://localhost:8000/storage/report_27-05-19_05.xlsx`

#### Serving file

You can also use Laravel / PHP to serve the file, trough your controller.

2. Retrieve files trough the controller:

```php
$filename = "Example.docx";
return response()->download(storage_path("app/reports/{$fileName}"));
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but I get binary file in response network instead downloading file

Comment: Could I get binary response in client and open in new window using js?

Comment: @OPV If you receive an binary stream instead of an file download, it suggest something is wrong with your webserver configuration. Laravel already set the right headers by default, when using the response, download function.